# Google Earth Engine - only extract values for each point based on a corresponding date

Tags: google-earth-engine, climate

I have a list of occurrence points that I am collecting data for. Each point was collected on a specific date, with little overlap among when each organism was detected (data file with dates and collection points [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/ckglidden/lu_long_pres_ES)).

I am trying to extract values from the TerraClimate ImageCollections for each occurrence point, but only for the corresponding date. So far, I have managed to subset the ImageCollection down to all of the dates the data were collected (so for each point, there is a value for for when it was collected along values for the dates all of the other occurrence points were collected. Is there a way to update my code so that I am on extracting the values that aligns with the collection month-year for each occurrence point?

Code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7ea99c65cd02fde4d941cd9e4ae61504) and below:

```
//functions
function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}

//read in points
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/user/lu_long_pres_ES');

var pts_buffer = pts.map(bufferPoints(500, true)); //square pixel

//read in climate data
var startDate = '1986-01-01'
var endDate = '2017-08-01'

///read in date list and subset image collection to dates
var dates = ee.FeatureCollection('users/user/dates')

var date2list = ee.List(dates.reduceColumns({
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(1),
                    selectors: ['date']
                  })
                   .get('list'))
                   .flatten();

var date_list = date2list.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date.parse({format:'"y-M-d"',
                        date: ee.String(date)})
                        .millis();
});

var climate = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE")
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)

var climate = climate.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleTime', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis());
});

var climate_sub = climate.filter(ee.Filter.inList("simpleTime", date_list));

//get image for each month and year within the date subset
var climate_monthly = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.List.sequence(1, 2).map(function(y){
  var total_precip = climate_sub.map(function (image) {
   return image.select(['pr'])
   }).toBands();

  var mintemp = climate_sub.map(function (image) {
    return image.select(['tmmn'])
   }).toBands();

  var maxtemp = climate_sub.map(function (image) {
    return image.select(['tmmx'])
   }).toBands();
   
   var wind_speed = climate_sub.map(function (image) {
    return image.select(['vs'])
   }).toBands();
   
return ee.Image.cat(total_precip, mintemp, maxtemp, wind_speed);
})).toBands();

//"reduce" climate to the 1000m buffer zone
var climate_point_monthly = climate_monthly.reduceRegions({
  collection: pts_buffer, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you're doing, map over the occurrence points and filter the image collection to just that date and run a reduceRegion on the matching image for the one point.